# How to get span tag inside a div in jQuery and assign a text?

Tags: jquery, find, element

I use the following ,

```
<div id='message' style="display: none;">
  <span></span>
 <a href="#" class="close-notify">X</a>
</div>
```

Now i want to find the span inside the div and assign a text to it...

```
function Errormessage(txt) {
    $("#message").fadeIn("slow");
    // find the span inside the div and assign a text
    $("#message a.close-notify").click(function() {
        $("#message").fadeOut("slow");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#message span").text("hello world!");
```

See it in your code!

```
function Errormessage(txt) {
    var m = $("#message");

    // set text before displaying message
    m.children("span").text(txt);

    // bind close listener
    m.children("a.close-notify").click(function(){
      m.fadeOut("slow");
    });

    // display message
    m.fadeIn("slow");
}
```

Comment: @rahul, I was a bit confused. No worries :)

Answer (score 23):

```
$("#message > span").text("your text");
```

or

```
$("#message").find("span").text("your text");
```

or

```
$("span","#message").text("your text");
```

or

```
$("#message > a.close-notify").siblings('span').text("your text");
```

Comment: How about if you already have the JQuery object that is `message`?

Comment: @douglasg14b I have the same question.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
$("#message span").text("hello world!");

function Errormessage(txt) {
    var elem = $("#message");
    elem.fadeIn("slow");
    // find the span inside the div and assign a text
    elem.children("span").text("your text");

    elem.children("a.close-notify").click(function() {
        elem.fadeOut("slow");
    });
}
```

Comment: @rahul, you should probably set the text and bind the listener before displaying the contents of `#message`

Answer (score 0):

```
function Errormessage(txt) {
    $("#message").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#message span:first").text(txt);
    // find the span inside the div and assign a text
    $("#message a.close-notify").click(function() {
        $("#message").fadeOut("slow");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla JS, without jQuery:

```
document.querySelector('#message span').innerHTML = 'hello world!'
```

Available in all browsers: https://caniuse.com/#search=querySelector

Answer (score 0):

It will find the  tag into  tag and set text to span.

$('div').find('span').text('Your text');